# Can I use with statements in python with a list?

Tags: python, exception, with-statement

When I process one file, I can use `with` statement to ensure it is always closed, on success or failure. Such as

```
with open('some_file', 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

However, I now need to open a list of files, the number of which is only known at runtime, so I cannot use nested with statements. But can I use it with a list? Kind of like

```
with [open(fn) for fn in file_names] as files:
     #do something
```

The above obviously doesn't work. What will work?

Comment: You want to open all files at once, or one by one?

Comment: @Marcin: I need to open all files at once, because I need to write to different file based on the streamed in data.

Comment: In this case, i think you have no choice except using normal `f = open('workfile', 'r')` instead of `with`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marcin mentioned in the comments, I don't believe there is a way to do this using a list and `with`.

However, [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is essentially *syntactic sugar* for a set of `try`/`except`/`finally` blocks that allows for encapsulation and therefore easier reuse.

While you can specify multiple pairings within a single `with`, i.e.

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f, open('bar.txt', 'r') as f2:
    pass    # do stuff here
```

There's not an allowance for dynamic variables there such as `list`s or `tuple`s. This form is actually treated as if the comma-separated expressions are nested `with`s.

However, what you could do instead is essentially ignore the *syntactic sugar* of `with` and rely on the original syntax it was meant to replace. That is, encapsulate your logic within a set of `try`/`except`/`finally` blocks. That way, you can open a list of files at runtime, and then ensure via the `finally` clause that they get cleaned up.

Something of the form:

```
try:
    files = [open(fn) for fn in file_names]

    # do stuff with files
except:
    # handle exceptions as needed here
finally:
    for f in files:
        f.close();

    # and any other cleanup you want to do
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the [`contextlib.nested`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested) manager of the `contextlib` module is designed for. You can use it like this:

```
from contextlib import nested

with nested(*[open(fn) for fn in file_names]) as files:
    # files is a list of file objects
```

Note however that as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested), this function has been deprecated since Python2.7 because of two quirks. I will let you judge whether or not you can live with them in the application you have in mind.

I think this is also a good time to mention the little-known *multiple manager form* of the `with` statement explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). Even though it doesn't apply to your case, I think it is good to know it exists.